# How to pass multiple parameter for laravel route in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

```
var url = "{{ route('order-detail',':slug') }}";
console.log(url);
```

I want to add one more parameter `id` after `slug`:

```
var url = "{{ route('order-detail',':slug',':id') }}";
console.log(url);
```

This is the error:

> Missing required parameter for [Route: order-detail] [URI:
> orders/detail/{slug}/{id}] [Missing parameter: id]. (View:
> /var/www/html/projectname/Modules/Orders/Resources/views/new-orders.blade.php)

Comment: Fun fact, if this code is within a `<script>` in a `.blade.php` file (which I suspect it is due to you being able to use `{{ }}`) you can simply do `var url = "{{ route('order-detail', ['slug' => $slug, 'id' => $id]) }}";` if `$slug` and `$id` are available as PHP variables. If not, use the answer below to replace your dummy values of `':slug:'` and `':id'` with their JS variable counterparts.

Comment: @TimLewis Just a sidenote. Using the laravel variables directly this way sometimes doesn't just work for me. Perhaps I've been doing it wrongly or something haha. I'd rather use dummy values with a JavaScript ```replace()```.

Comment: @Innovin Yeah, sometimes that can indeed have issues depending on what `$id` and `$slug` contains (i.e. if for some reason it has `"` or `'` in it), but you can also typically get around that by using PHP's `urlencode()` to replace those with `%22` for `"` or `%27` for `'`. I like the solution with JS replaces though! I haven't had to use that much, since you can also use `var url = \`{{ url('/whatever') }}/${id}/{$slug}\`;` (interpolation, etc.). Definitely lots of ways to accomplish this 

Comment: @TimLewis Ah. Good ol JavaScript template literals. Nice one! Using laravel ```url()``` helper function can be nice. But if you're someone like me who never bothers to know what my urls actually are after I have created them(I rather use route names which are very short and concise), it might just be a pain in the a$$ :)

Comment: @Innovin Totally agreed! Generally you'd prefer to use `route('example.index)` over `url('/example')`, but `url()` doesn't blow up when you omit parameters, which allows you to append them after the fact like in my example 

Answer (score 2):

First off, create two variables `slug` and `id`

```js
var slug = ...;
var id = ...;
// you should know how to get this, you didn't show your full code
// so I can't know
```

Next, create your `url` variable like this:

```js
var url = "{{ route('order-detail', ['slug' => ':slug', 'id' => ':id']) }}";
url = url.replace(':id', id);
url = url.replace(':slug', slug);
```

Now this should give you an appropriate route `url`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var url = "{{ route('order-detail', [':slug', ':id']) }}";
```